# Every linearly ordered topological space is shrinking

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

We say that $X$ is a *l*inearly *o*rdered *t*opological *s*pace (LOTS) if $X$ has the order topology induced by a linear order on $X$.

On the other hand, we say that $X$ is a *shrinking space* if every open cover has a *shrinking*, i.e., if for every open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$ there exists an open refinement $\mathcal{V}=\{V_U:U\in\mathcal{U}\}$ such that $\overline{V_U}\subset U$ for all $U\in\mathcal{U}$.

While searching about shrinking spaces on the web, I came across [this note](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/tag/shrinking-space/), where the author claims that every LOTS is a shrinking space.

Since I was not able to prove this fact, I did some *digging*. However, the only reference I found is a paper from Fleischman (On coverings of linearly ordered spaces, 1970), which I am not able to get.

So I would like to ask for hints on how to prove that every LOTS is a shrinking space, or at least another reference where the proof can be found.

Comment: Every LOTS is (completely) normal. On the other hand, every space is normal if and only if it is shrinking. Hence te result.

Comment: @Dog_69 shrinking is only the same as normality if we restrict to point-finite covers e.g., not all open covers. Read the quoted note...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma True. I have forgotten that condition from Willard's theorem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every LOTS is monotonically normal, and as such normal and countably paracompact. The note you quoted proves that this implies that a LOTS is shrinking (we only need normal and countably metacompact).

Comment: I was not aware of the first fact. Thank you.